# cloud-sql-proxy works with telent fails with mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication, google-cloud-sql, telnet, cloud-sql-proxy

I've got a GCP Cloud SQL instance, and I'm trying connect via the `mysql` client program on the shell via `cloud-sql-proxy` (version 2).

I start the proxy as such

```
cloud-sql-proxy project:regon:name -g 
2023/04/29 23:15:30 Authorizing with gcloud user credentials
2023/04/29 23:15:32 [project:regon:name] Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306
2023/04/29 23:15:32 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!
```

`netstat` confirms the proxy is listening on the expected host and port

```
netstat -ant | grep :3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Connecting via `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3306` fails, there's no output from the proxy when I run this either

```
mysql -v -h 127.0.0.1 -u myuser -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

However if I try via `telnet`, it seems to work

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Q
/m7bEb j-Z(%G
             L[mysql_native_password
```

and there's output from the proxy to boot

```
2023/04/29 23:15:39 [project:regon:name] instance closed the connection
2023/04/29 23:22:22 [project:regon:name] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:58854
```

I can connect with `gcloud sql connect project:regon:name --user=myuser`, however I want to connect via `mysql` so I can chain it to other programs on the shell.

<strike>The `mysql` client binary I have is from ubuntu.</strike> Short of building it from scratch with debugging flags, can someone help me connect to my Cloud SQL instance via `cloud-sql-proxy`?

UPDATE:

I realized I'm mapping `mysql` to `docker run -it --rm mysql:8 mysql $@;`

Comment: The problem only makes sense if you have an old version of the client. What is the output from `mysql -V`?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Ahh, it looks like I have `mysql` mapped to a shell command `docker run -it --rm mysql:8 mysql $@`; if I download `mysql-client-core-5.7` I start getting meaningful error messages

Comment: That would explain why `mysql` is not actually connecting to the proxy. It is connecting to localhost inside the container and not the host.

Comment: Thanks, I think when I setup my machine some time back I wanted to stay away from ubuntu packages. Shot myself in the foot this time!

Comment: Post an answer with details on how you set up the `mysql` cli to run from a container. A possible solution and still use a container is to set up the container network. IIRC `--network=host` will work OR use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` for the MySQL command running inside the container. In other words, there is a solution to continue using the command inside a container.

Comment: Wow, you got it without looking, adding `--network=host` to the docker command works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the `mysql` binary on my system with `which mysql`, I discovered instead of installing the binary from Apt like I'd assumed, I was instead using a thin wrapper script

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -it --rm mysql:8 mysql $@
```

The goal being to install as few packages from Apt as possible. However I forgot, and since `cloud-sql-proxy` is listening on `127.0.0.1` *on the host*, I was passing `-h 127.0.0.1` to the `mysql` command...

Docker was routing this to the local interface on the container instead of the host. Adding the `--network=host` flag to the container command passes the `-h 127.0.0.1` flag to `mysql` to the host, and everything works as expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -it --network=host --rm mysql:8 mysql $@
```